# Is there a way to reuse patterns in a RegExp?

Tags: regular-expressions

Somethimes I need a RegExp which uses a complex pattern multiple times. If I copy the same pattern there it works, but this is error prone as I then need to change each occurence of the pattern individualy if I want to make changes in the future.

Is there a way to either name a pattern, or even better, store it somewhere so that I can reuse it over multiple functions?

Consider the following code:

```
(defun complex-stuff ()
  ""
  (interactive)
  (beginning-of-buffer)
  (save-excursion 
    (query-replace-regexp  
      "a \\(<complex-patten>\\) b \\(<complex-pattern>\\)"
      "x \\1 y \\2")))
```

Here, `<complex-pattern>` is some valid expression that I wish to reuse.

Comment: @sds: It's fine this way for me. I can see in separate lines which expression will be replaced by which other What would you do differently?

Comment: Hit `TAB` on each line and Emacs will indent it. Avoid hanging parens. Look at the  [conventions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coding-Conventions.html). I am sure it looks fine to YOU, but you write code for others (and yourself down the road) to read, not just for the computer to execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [regular expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regular-Expressions.html) is just a string, so you can store it as such in a variable:

```
(defvar my-complex-patters "....")
(re-search-forward (concat "a \\(" my-complex-patters "\\)"))
```

or even

```
(re-search-forward (format "a \\(%s\\)" my-complex-patters))
```

**NB**: Please note that [`query-replace-regexp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Query-Replace.html) is a fairly complicated command which depends on many user options. Its use in code is fragile and thus is discouraged.

You should do something like this instead:

```
(while (re-search-forward ... nil t)
  (replace-match ...))
```

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions are just strings in Elisp, so you can assign them as the value of a variable like any other Elisp value. For example:

```el
(defvar my-complex-pattern "\\(<complex-pattern>\\)"
  "Regular expression matching desired filename.")

(defun complex-stuff ()
  "Do complex stuff."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (save-excursion
    (query-replace-regexp
     (apply #'format "a %s b %s" (make-list 2 my-complex-pattern))
     "x \\1 y \\2")))
```

You can also locally assign the regular expression to a let-bound variable like so:

```el
(defun complex-stuff ()
  "Do complex stuff."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (save-excursion
    (query-replace-regexp
     (let ((patt "\\(<complex-pattern>\\)"))
       (apply #'format "a %s b %s" (make-list 2 patt)))
     "x \\1 y \\2")))
```

An alternative to using `concat` and `format` to dynamically construct regular expressions is `rx-to-string` (see documentation for macro `rx`):

```el
(defun complex-stuff ()
  "Do complex stuff."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (save-excursion
    (query-replace-regexp
     (let ((patt `(regexp ,my-complex-pattern)))
       (rx-to-string `(: "a " ,patt "b " ,patt)))
     "x \\1 y \\2")))
```

As a side note, the documentation for `beginning-of-buffer` suggests using `(goto-char (point-min))` instead of it when writing lisp.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer! As I have little to no Lisp skill, I accepted @sds's answer for giving me the easy and "dirty" solution I was hoping for. You definitively also have my upvote, but I'll need to get to 15 points before you'll actually feel the effect.

Comment: @Shylock Thanks for the appreciation. On the contrary, I think my answer is the "dirty" solution in this case, as sds correctly describes and gives pointers to the ideal way of doing things. This is why I upvoted that answer. I think the only advantage my answer has is that it involves a lower learning curve for someone unfamiliar with Elisp regexps.